# How to debug Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'newString' was corrupted

Tags: string, c++11, vector, runtime-error

This is a function to convert a long string (sentence) into a vector of strings. From the error, it seems obvious that the char ptr newString is causing some access violation, run-time issues. Probably it's length is the root cause?

Also, please note that the output of the function is just coming as expected, but with the run-time error occurring.

```
vector<string> convertStrgToStrVect(char *inString)
{
    unsigned int end = 0, start = 0, i = 0, len = 0, j = 0;
    char *inStr = inString, *s;
    char newString[] = "";
    vector<unsigned int> startLenVect, endLenVect, strLenVect;
    vector<unsigned int> :: iterator itr1, itr2;
    vector<string> stringVect;
    vector<string> :: iterator itr3;

    s = inStr;

    // Add an extra space an the end of the string
    for( i = 0; i < strlen(s); i++)
    {
    }
    s[i] = ' ';
    i++;
    s[i] = '\0';

    cout << s << endl;
    cout << strlen(s) << endl;

    // Create vectors for start and end indexes to split the words separated by a space
    for( i = 0; i < strlen(s); i++)
    {
        if(s[i] != ' ')
        {
            end++;
            len = end - start;
        }
        else
        {
            endLenVect.push_back(end);
            startLenVect.push_back(start);
            strLenVect.push_back(len);
            end = i+1;
            start = i+1;
        }
    }
    cout << "startLenVect: ";
    for(itr1 = startLenVect.begin(); itr1 != startLenVect.end(); itr1++)
    {
        cout << *itr1 << " ";
    }

    cout << "endLenVect: ";
    for(itr1 = endLenVect.begin(); itr1 != endLenVect.end(); itr1++)
    {
        cout << *itr1 << " " << endl;
    }

    for(itr1 = startLenVect.begin(), itr2 = endLenVect.begin(); itr1 != startLenVect.end(); itr1++, itr2++)
    {
        strcpy(newString, "");
        for(i = *itr1, j = 0; i < *itr2; i++, j++)
        {
            newString[j] = s[i];
        }
        newString[j] = '\0';

        stringVect.push_back(newString);
    }

    for(itr3 = stringVect.begin(); itr3 != stringVect.end(); itr3++)
    {
        cout << "stringVect: " << *itr3 << endl;
    }
    return stringVect;
}
```

Comment: `char newString[] = "";` makes `newString` an array of 1 (one) character. `newString[j]` exhibits undefined behavior for any `j != 0`, by way of accessing an index out of bounds.

Comment: Thank you for your input @ Igor Tandetnik. But, I get the output fine, as below. If there were a problem in constructing newString, then shouldn't that not affect stringVect? I mean, it should not have got constructed.. right?

Comment: stringVect: This
stringVect: is
stringVect: earth

Comment: Undefined behavior is undefined. "Seems to work" is one possible manifestation of undefined behavior. That said, if everything worked fine, you wouldn't be here asking this question, would you?

Comment: Sure @Igor Tandetnik .. can you please suggest what to use instead of char newString[] = ""; ? I tried using the single pointer to char syntax, but the run-time exception persists. Also, a couple of debug statements showed that newString[j], was holding a valid char value (at least when it was printed to the console out).

Comment: Looking closer, you don't need `newString` at all. The whole body of the loop using it can be replaced with `stringVect.emplace_back(s + *itr1, *itr2 - *itr1);`